# Erro ao formatar string com número

Tags: c#, string

Quero formatar uma string para que a mesma tenha seis dígitos preenchidos com zeros à esquerda.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.Quant.ToString());
```

Ele está retornando o seguinte:

```
67 = 00067
19 = 00019
 5 = 0005
 9 = 0009
```

Está sendo gerado apenas três zeros apenas e o número recebido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se `linha.Quant` for do tipo `int` remova o `ToString()` não é necessário:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000000}", 1.ToString())); //1 - não formata
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000000}", 1));            //000001
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000000}", 10));           //000010
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000000}", 67));           //000067
```

[Exemplo Online](http://ideone.com/UwaFwq)

Mas uma boa seria com [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) onde:

`totalWidth` é o número inteiro que informar a quantidade de caracteres, e o segundo parâmetro se for informado `paddingChar` preenche o restante da `string` com o carácter informado (se não for informado é colocado no lugar ***espaço***).

```
System.Console.WriteLine(5.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'));  //000005
System.Console.WriteLine(67.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')); //000067
System.Console.WriteLine(19.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')); //000019
System.Console.WriteLine(9.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'));  //000009
```

[Exemplo OnLine](http://ideone.com/SyazAo)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Método String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Método String.PadLeft (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0zk6ydzx(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.PadLeft (Int32, Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)