# Zeros à esquerda

Tags: vb.net

Vou receber vários números que podem ser de até 9 dígitos. Gostaria que quando não fosse de 9 (111 por exemplo) o sistema automaticamente substituísse por 000000111.

Os exemplos que eu achei na internet colocavam para preencher números fixos a esquerda, eu não posso utilizar os mesmos pois posso receber 11 e teria que aparecer 000000011.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) resolveria para o seu caso:

```
Dim pad As Char
str = "11"
pad = "0"c
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(11, pad))
```

Outra possibilidade encontrada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183924/64073):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00000000000}", 11));
```